# Automatically start AWS module when VSCode is started

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, aws-sdk

Is it possible to have the AWS SDK module loaded once VS Code starts?

Running on OSX, VSCode has the PowerShell extension installed and working.

In a terminal I can type "powershell" and it automatically loads the AWS module because "Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1" has

> *Import-Module AWSPowerShell.NetCore*
>
> *Set-DefaultAWSRegion -Region eu-west-1*

in there so they are loaded once I start PowerShell.

I was hoping to have the same in VSCode and not having to add these 2 lines inside the PowerShell script(s).

Answer (score 0):

You can add your modules and scripts to launch.json to facilitate this.

More detail can be found at the following link:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2017/02/13/debugging-powershell-script-in-visual-studio-code-part-2/

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this!